# Times in linux Time output

Tags: linux

I run time on my c program and the following was printed:

```
0.00user 0.03system 0:00.03elapsed 91%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1632maxresident)k
0inputs+112outputs (0major+143minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

My main question concerns the numbers before user, system, and elapsed. Does the output say:

user takes 0.00 seconds, system takes 0.03 seconds, and elapsed takes 0.03 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that would depend on what your c program is displaying. c programs by default don't print any timestamps, etc.

From what you listed above, it looks similar to the output of the standard linux TOP program that is included in most/all distros.

It would indicate what percentage of CPU time has been spent on that classification of code (user space code, system space code, etc). The 0:00.03 would be the total uptime for your system usually.